# What Is the Point of Doing the Zero Padding?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft, speech-processing, speech-recognition

What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing Zero-padding, in particular the case of speech signals?

Comment: @MBaz wrong. Impossible duplicate. Completely different question. I ask the advantages and disadvantages of zero-padding, in particular the case of speech signals. Any input?

Comment: Do you have a **real** question in your mind or just want a **puzzle**?  Zero padding is the process of appending zeros to the end of a shorter sequence to make it trivially longer. It has **consequences** but not kind of advantages or disadvantages. So if you have any real question in your mind, please ask it straight.

Comment: @Fat32 is this a site only for questions that you consider real? C'mon, I'm here to learn :) Sorry if my question is a puzzle for you. ;)

Comment: @Fat32 you and me both ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think of it as efficient way to apply [Dirichlet Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) Based interpolation in the Fourier Domain.

The advantage of applying the interpolation using Zero Padding in the Time Domain is very simple - it is simpler and more computationally efficient.

Comment: but MBaz is correct.  there are other answers that speak to zero-padding.  using zero-padding in one domain does accomplish a specific form of interpolation in the reciprocal domain.  but one is not completely able to define the form of that interpolation using zero-padding.  if it's **only** zero-padding, you are essentially applying a rectangular window to that segment of signal.  you can window with something other than a rectangular window, and the result is convolving the spectrum with something other than a dirichlet sinc function.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, We can always extend the question asked. But answering directly on what is written is given zero padding and not zero padding and...